# Crystal Report - How to add 1 year in year label

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am connecting Crystal Report to VB.Net and designing my crystal report view. I already got how to get current Year only on the Date date label (I'm inserting it using "Insert > Special Field > Date date"). Now my problem is how can I get the current year AND add 1 year to it.

My desired output is this:

```
School Year: 2015 - 2016
```

My current output is this:

```
School Year: 2015 -
```

I don't know if there is like a coding part/view in the report (.rpt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For current year +1 you have to create one formula in crystal report

@NextYear

[image]

Right click on formula,provide a name as NextYear

[image]

And put the formula in the work area.Click on SAVE & CLOSE..

Year(CurrentDate) + 1

Comment: How can I create a formula? Sorry I'm a newb in CR

Comment: show the formula you are using to get School Year: 2015 -

Comment: So I manage to add a formula, How can I apply it to the label?

Comment: Oh I got it now. Thanks! :D